# Cron expression unable to work as expected

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler in my project.

I put cron expression for every 4 hour, but still my job is running after every one minute.

Cronexpression:

```
0 0 0/4 1/1 * ? *
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: try 0 0 */4 ? * *

Comment: Is your job successful? I am not an expert but I am guessing if the job is failing and misfire is not configured it may attempt retries. Apart from that 0 0 0/4 * * ? * also should be working.

Comment: Yes, job is successful.  It is printing correct cron in logs also but it didn't not run as per cron.

Comment: Did you check in http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think following is the cause, please find the document:

- http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html

> Support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month value is not complete (you must currently use the ‘?’ character in one of these fields).

Actually, I tried your cron expression on cron online tester, return error.

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

[image]